# Empty DataFrame when filtering by date in pandas even when dates match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with two pandas DataFrames, result and forecast. I want to filter the forecast DataFrame based on the index values from the result DataFrame. However, when I try to filter it, I get an empty DataFrame despite having the same date values in both DataFrames.

Here's my code:

```
result = forecast.groupby(['date', 'profile', 'combination'])['cur_price'].min().to_frame().fillna(0).astype(int)
for date_, profile, combination in result.index:
    comp = forecast[
        (forecast['date'] == date_) &
        (forecast['profile'] == profile) &
        (forecast['combination'] == combination)
    ]['competitors']
```

I've already checked the data types of the 'date' column in both DataFrames, and they are the same (datetime64[ns]). But still, the comp DataFrame is empty.

Why is comp empty even though the date values in result and forecast match? How can I properly filter the forecast DataFrame based on the index values from the result DataFrame?

Comment: Your `comp` variable is being overwritten in every iteration of the for loop. The value of `comp` is the result of the last value of `result.index`. You can take a look at [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-objects).

Comment: Some sample data demonstrating the problem would help to solve it.

Comment: try modifying the `for statement` - `for index, row in result.iteritems():` 
`date_, profile, combination = index`